# Regression Output Interpretation: I am too dumb ... (2min solution?)

Tags: regression, interpretation, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I read this paper on firm performance in a prestigious journal and can absolutely not explain how the authors came to this conclusion:

*The estimated increase in the level of **overall economic performance (OEP)** attributable to VC-backing is equal to **+41%** (Investor A) and **+50%** (Investor B), respectively.*

Model (simplified; Fixed-Effects Regression): **OEP = ß0+ ß1*Log(FirmAge) + ß2*log(TotalAssets) + ß3*InvestorADummy + ß4*InvestorBDummy + ErrorTerm + firm-specific unobserved effects**

**Output (simplified, both significant)**

- InvestorA Estimate 0.3411
- InvestorB Estimate 0.7865

How do the authors arise from an estimate of 0.3411 and 0.7865 to an interpretation of 41% and 50% dependent variable increase?

**Maybe important for output interpretation**: Dependent variable --> *"In this work, we use the GMM system method developed by Blundell and Bond (2000), which solves the problems related to the weak correlations between the current growth rates of a firm’s real sales value, fixed assets and payroll expenses, and the lagged levels of these variables. More specifically, we model a series of industry-specific firm- level Cobb–Douglas production functions with a first-order autoregressive component in the error term, where the coefficient of the autoregressive component must be lower than one to ensure stationarity to the model. We use real sales value as output variable, and its logarithm as dependent variable. As inputs, we use the logarithm of real payroll expenses and the logarithm of real fixed assets. The arguments of the logarithmic functions for the output and input variables are augmented by one."*

Does the fact that OEP is based on log input variables have any impact on the interpretation?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. exp(0.3411) = 1.4065 which is indeed a 41% increase.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks for the answer! This helps a lot especially as it might be so easy. However, since exp(0.7865) = 2.195, how do I arrive at the 51% increase?